# How Can I Assure that All of My WinForm Displays?

Tags: winforms, runtime, visual-studio-2019

I've created a Windows form in Visual Studio 2019 that looks like this at design time:

[image]

At run time, though, the bottom half of the form is unceremoniously truncated:

[image]

The dimensions of the form (its Size properties) are height 800, width 640.

What do I need to do to get the entire form to display at runtime?

Comment: WinForms on Net.Core or Net.Framework?

Comment: Net.Framework and so it goes (I had to add the rest, though superfluous)

Comment: Is that a form displayed as modal with ShowDialog? Usually these forms have no resizing borders and buttons.

Comment: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103) -- Also, that *warning* you see in Visual Studio is not a joke: design at `100%`. If you find that the interface Fonts are too small, you can adjust the layout in the environment Options. ++ Add your Controls to containers (Panels / nested Panels, TableLayoutPanels, FlowLayoutPanels etc), don't let them *float around* (ever).

Comment: @Steve: WindowState is normal; it is the main and only form, so it shouldn't be be using ShowDialog.

Comment: @Jimi: Restarting VS with 100% scaling, then adding the application manifest file to the project and replacing what was in it by copying-and-pasting the stuff from Hans Passant works just fine. Thanks to you and Hans!